# jQuery UI tabs with smooth dropdown effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How to add smooth closing and opening effect to dropdown UI tabs like here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/?

My code below:

```js
$("#wsparcie_tabs_container").tabs({
    collapsible: true,
    active: false
});
```

```html
<div id="wsparcie_tabs_container">
  <ul class="tabs home-wsparcie-tabs">
    <li><a href="#tab_1_contents" class="wsparcie_tab"><span>One</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab_2_contents" class="wsparcie_tab"><span>Two</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab_3_contents" class="wsparcie_tab"><span>Three</span></a></li>
  </ul>
    
<div class="clear"></div>
    
  <div id="tab_1_contents">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
  </div>
  <div id="tab_2_contents">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
  </div>
  <div id="tab_3_contents">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
  </div>
</div><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can use slideToggle for this

Comment: Yes it could work. But please take a look on my code, tabs going crazy: https://jsfiddle.net/oah2wcnp/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery has some built in functions for this, e.g. slideDown:

```
$(selector).slideDown(speed,callback);
```

Here you can read more about the jquery slide.

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_slide.asp

edit: here is a simple example
https://jsfiddle.net/we19rs07/19/

edit2: it is even easier with the jquery-gui tab:
https://jsfiddle.net/b4ufmvjg/

Comment: OK got it, thanks. But by code going crazy when try to clik it. https://jsfiddle.net/oah2wcnp/1/

Comment: @Mike just found out that it is even easier with jquery-gui, take a look at this 
 https://jsfiddle.net/h5u0976q/5/

Comment: Yes this is what I need! You are my hero bro. But is there any way to stop page jumping to anchor when clicking tab?

Comment: not working in my case. This helps: ```$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#wsparcie_tabs_container").bind('tabsselect', function(event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();  // This will kill the default behavior.
            window.location.href = ui.tab;
        });
});``` but killing also other tabs on my page.

Comment: OK, I changed your code, and this works for me: ```$("#wsparcie_tabs_container").tabs({
    collapsible: true,
    active: false,
    fx: { height: 'toggle', duration: 'slow' }
}).find( 'ul.ui-tabs-nav li a' ).bind( 'click', function(event, ui){
      event.preventDefault();
      window.location.href = ui.tab;
});```